# Android Intent Filter on tablet

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm encountering some problem in Android Intent Filter.

```
    <activity android:name=".view.SampleActivity" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="sample.test.com.my"
                android:pathPrefix="/resetPassword"
                android:scheme="test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the one I put in AndroidManifest.xml. It works in phone but however I realized it does not work in tablet.

What could be the problem since it works on phone but not tablet?

UPDATE: Found the issue. The root cause is related to the link provided is different for tablet and phone. There is nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 0):

Your AndroidManifest file should contain a default activity.
In the Intent filter, you may add the following code.

```
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 

 </intent-filter>
```

It should contain a MAIN and LAUNCHER category.

Comment: Ya. Already have one of this for the default activity. The intent filter above is to allow the device to open the app's reset password screen when a link is clicked in the browser.